# Sub Report not showing (rdl)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

i am trying to make a rdl report which also contain a sub report. everything work fine when i preview the report.but after i deployed the report n sub report and trying to run it through the program i get an error."sub report could not be shown"

```
            this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.50.187/ReportServer");
            this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ReportServer/ChartOfAccounts";

            this.ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;

            IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("Report_user", "ipix.123", "IPIXSOLUTIONS");
            this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
            ReportParameter[] parm = new ReportParameter[3];

            parm[0] = new ReportParameter("company_ID", Convert.ToString(4));

            parm[1] = new ReportParameter("accntGrplvl1_ID", Convert.ToString(1));

            parm[2] = new ReportParameter("accntGrplvl2_ID", Convert.ToString(2));
            this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm);

           this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

this is my code.do i have to provide some code for sub report too?.both ma reports are in same folder.and parameter to the sub report is taken from main report itself..where did i go wrong?

Comment: is there additional parameters used for subreport?

Comment: yes company_ID used for subreport-sreerag

Comment: did u assigned all those in the design?

Comment: yeah..everything work fine in preview problem is when i run it through the program after deploy..(it works fine in report server too !!).do i have to write C# code for sub report too..like in rdlc?